# Compressing extJS code (only components that i trully need)

Tags: extjs

A long time ago i saw on `www.sencha.com` utility (or whatever this was, i dont remember).

This utility can compress those components that i need (for example datepickers, diagrams and so on) and ext-all.js can be less than 1mb.

And i need to do it, but how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about [jsbuilder](http://www.sencha.com/products/jsbuilder). They are still supporting it.

The utility uses [.jsb2](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/JSBuilder2/JSB2FileFormat.txt) file to configure the elements to include in resulting package and [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) to minimize it.

Answer (score 3):

Download [Sencha SDK Tools](http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/) 
and install it.

Run the following commands in your index directory:

```
sencha create jsb -a index.html  -p site.jsb3
sencha build -p site.jsb3 -d .
```

This will create app-all.js with only the classes that your index file requires to run.

Finally create a new index that uses the generated app-all.js:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
              <script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="app-all.js"></script>
      <title>Your Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

You still need to load the core ext.js.